# Unable to select the text from the drop down

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

i tried to identify the text from the drop down but it displays the error.

```
Select agentName1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("XYZ")));
agentName1.selectByVisibleText("ABC");
```

i tried with `agentName1.selectByIndex(32) & agentName1.selectByValue("587");` but every time during my automation run i have to create the new text due this the index and value is changed due to this selenium is unable to locate the element.

i tried clicking the drop down it worked but selecting the text from the dropdown is not working.

i tried all the possible way displayed in the forum but no luck.

Please help me on to resolve the issue.

[image]

tried below code as well.

```
WebElement agentDropDown1 = driver.findElement(By.name("baseline"));
Select categories1 = new Select(agentDropDown1);

// 2. getting all options of menu

java.util.List<WebElement> optionsList1 = categories1.getOptions();
System.out.println("The options list : ");
for (WebElement option : optionsList1) {
       System.out.println(option.getText());
}

System.out.println();

// 3. selecting dropdown menu 

categories1.selectByValue("1426");
```

Comment: which website ? are there 32 elements ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagname("option"));
 list.get(<index number of the selection>).click();
```